# Measure string size in Bytes in php

Tags: php, string, string-length

I am doing a real estate feed for a portal and it is telling me the max length of a string should be 20,000 bytes (20kb), but I have never run across this before.

How can I measure `byte` size of a `varchar string`. So I can then do a while loop to trim it down.

Comment: there shouldn't be any problem getting a string to that length is there what is it telling you ? what errors are you seeing ????

Comment: byte size -> ```strlen()``` ex: ```strlen('a₹')``` -> ```4```. character count -> ```mb_strlen()``` ex: ```mb_strlen('a₹', "UTF-8")``` -> ```2```. Note: ```mb_strlen()``` is disabled by default in php.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to figure out if the string is ascii encoded or encoded with a multi-byte format.

In the former case, you can just use `strlen`.

In the latter case you need to find the number of bytes per character.

the strlen documentation gives an example of how to do it : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#72274

Comment: strlen is not mb-safe function and actually returns number of bytes, not of characters. If you want number of characters in multi-byte encoding, you have to use mb_strlen.

Comment: @Darhazer it is possible to overload `str*()` into `mb_str*()`, so calling `strlen` will indeed call `mb_strlen`. To see if this is enabled, check `mbstring.func_overload` in php.ini. Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: If you're looking for the number of **bytes** (which is what you asked for - *not* the number of characters) the correct answer was posted by @PhoneixS below; as pointed out by @Carlos `strlen()` isn't safe because it may be overloaded on some PHP installations.

Comment: @CarlosCampderrós Function overloading deprecated in PHP 7.2.0, removed in PHP 8.0.0. https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Answer (score 100):

You can use mb_strlen() to get the **byte length** using a encoding that only have byte-characters, without worring about multibyte or singlebyte strings.
For example, as drake127 saids in a comment of mb_strlen, you can use '8bit' encoding:

```
<?php
    $string = 'Cién cañones por banda';
    echo mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
?>
```

You can have problems using strlen function since php have an option to overload strlen to actually call mb_strlen. See more info about it in http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

For trim the string by byte length without split in middle of a multibyte character you can use:

```
mb_strcut(string $str, int $start [, int $length [, string $encoding ]] )
```

Answer (score 28):

Do you mean byte size or string length?

Byte size is measured with [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php), whereas string length is queried using [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php). You can use `substr()` to trim a string to X *bytes* (note that this will break the string if it has a multi-byte encoding - as pointed out by Darhazer in the comments) and `mb_substr()` to trim it to X characters in the encoding of the string.

Comment: strlen doesn't give you byte size.

Comment: @N.B.it gives you exactly the number of bytes... that's why there is mb_strlen() in the mb_ extension. Try strlen on multi-byte character to test...

Comment: @soulmerge if you use substr() on a multi-byte encoded string, you can break the last character in the string.

Comment: @Darhazer: You are correct but that's not something I had suggested doing. It is not stated that the string is indeed a multibyte string, either.

Comment: @N.B. There is a difference between `mb_strlen()` and `strlen()`, i.e. they are not aliases of each other. I have furthermore done enough network programming in PHP to know that it does give the byte length.

Comment: @soulmerge as Carlos Campderrós said in other answer, it is possible to overload str*() into mb_str*(), so calling strlen will indeed call mb_strlen. To see if this is enabled, check mbstring.func_overload in php.ini. Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: There is now [a note on the PHP manual page for `strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#refsect1-function.strlen-notes): "strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string." Not sure if that was there before, but it confirms that this answer is correct.

Comment: @PhoneixS Luckily, the function overloading "feature" has been removed as of PHP 8.0.0. Deprecated in 7.2.0. So you can now rely on `strlen` to return byte length of a string.

Answer (score 5):

PHP's [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function returns the number of ASCII characters.

`strlen('borsc')` -> 5 (bytes)

`strlen('boršč')` -> 7 (bytes)

```
$limit_in_kBytes = 20000;

$pointer = 0;
while(strlen($your_string) > (($pointer + 1) * $limit_in_kBytes)){
    $str_to_handle = substr($your_string, ($pointer * $limit_in_kBytes ), $limit_in_kBytes);
    // here you can handle (0 - n) parts of string
    $pointer++;
}

$str_to_handle = substr($your_string, ($pointer * $limit_in_kBytes), $limit_in_kBytes);
// here you can handle last part of string
```

.. or you can use a function like this:

```
function parseStrToArr($string, $limit_in_kBytes){
    $ret = array();

    $pointer = 0;
    while(strlen($string) > (($pointer + 1) * $limit_in_kBytes)){
        $ret[] = substr($string, ($pointer * $limit_in_kBytes ), $limit_in_kBytes);
        $pointer++;
    }

    $ret[] = substr($string, ($pointer * $limit_in_kBytes), $limit_in_kBytes);

    return $ret;
}

$arr = parseStrToArr($your_string, $limit_in_kBytes = 20000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Further to PhoneixS answer to get the correct length of string in bytes - Since `mb_strlen()` is slower than `strlen()`, for the best performance one can check "mbstring.func_overload" ini setting so that `mb_strlen()` is used only when it is really required:

```
$content_length = ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') ? mb_strlen($content , '8bit') : strlen($content);
```

Comment: Thankfully, this check is no longer needed as of PHP 8.0.0. The function overloading "feature" has been removed as of PHP 8.0.0, and deprecated in 7.2.0. So you can now rely on `strlen` to return byte length of a string.