# calculate Cookie Size in PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I wanted to read the cookie and calculate its length on server side using php, but can't find any direct method to do so. So how to achieve this task ?

Comment: 4 kilobytes per cookie, where the name and the OPAQUE_STRING combine to form the 4 kilobyte limit.

Comment: what do you mean by length ... ?is it size .. ?

Comment: @dreamCoder: yes it is the size

Answer (score 4):

what about this ?

```
setcookie("user", "Dino babu kannampuzha", time() + 3600);

if (isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
  $data = $_COOKIE["user"];
  $serialized_data = serialize($data);
  $size = strlen($serialized_data);
  echo 'Length : ' . strlen($data);
  echo "<br/>";
  echo 'Size : ' . ($size * 8 / 1024) . ' Kb';
}
```

// Output

```
Length : 21
Size : 0.232 Kb
```

Comment: Note that since the cookie will only be available after the page has been reloaded, the condition will be satisfied only *after* reload.

Comment: @Boaz : yea, u r rite. its just a sample.

Comment: +1 but does the size limit on cookies include data like expiry time?  (which isn't parsed into the $_COOKIE var)

Comment: isn't that 1024 instead of 1000 ?

Comment: http://extraconversion.com/data-storage/characters/characters-to-bytes.html
If 1 character = 1 byte then why you `n*8/1024` ? I'm very bad on math please excuse me, I'm really can't get it.

Answer (score 2):

To get the raw cookies and their length:

```
$rawCookies = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] : null;
$rawLength  = strlen($rawCookies);
echo $rawLength;
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen($_COOKIE['cookie_name'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but you can try this

```
$start_memory = memory_get_usage();
$cookie = $_COOKIE['YourCookie'];
echo memory_get_usage() - $start_memory-PHP_INT_SIZE * 8;


    <?php
    setcookie("TestCookie", '10');
    $start = memory_get_usage();
    $cookie = $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
    echo memory_get_usage() - $start;  //116 bytes   
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer from these resources:
http://extraconversion.com/data-storage/characters/characters-to-bytes.html
[Measure string size in Bytes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568949/measure-string-size-in-bytes-in-php)
https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

And my screenshot that get cookie size using Firebug.
[image]

I use my code from @Dino but change something such as `strlen` to `mb_strlen` to support unicode.
It becomes:

```
$data = $_COOKIE['user'];
$name = 'user';
if (!is_scalar($data)) {
    $data = serialize($data);
}
$size = mb_strlen($data)+mb_strlen($name);
echo 'Cookie name length : ' . mb_strlen($name) . "<br>\n";
echo 'Cookie content length : ' . mb_strlen($data) . "<br>\n";
echo 'Cookie size : ~' . ($size) . ' Bytes<br>'."\n";
```

Which is almost close to the size appears in Firebug. I really don't understand why the size must `(n*8/1024)` if we refer from the resources above it just 1 character 1 byte except unicode so I have to use `mb_strlen` instead of `strlen`.