# CodeIgniter set_flashdata method echo content to browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is very strange issue.
I have a running website which has no problem with me or any one i know.
but one of my clients told me that he have a strange codes so i asked him for a screen shot and here it's

[image: error with set_flashdata]

The code where this happen

```
$this->session->set_flashdata(array('success_msg' =>'Some message'));
redirect(base_url());
```

Redirect didn't happen and user get a content of his local cookie into the browser like what's in image , he uses Firefox and windows as os .

A gain I can't re produce this issue and he told me that happen to him every time he visit this page !

Any idea ?

Comment: is your client using a different language than you are? locale? etc; for their browser etc; What browser, also with the changed `set_flashdata()` are they still experiencing the issue. One last one, how much data do you have in your session? [Cookies can only hold 4KB](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15740581/158014) of data (if you use encryption this reduces your size!)

Comment: @Jakub no he uses the same language as i use , and cookie hold less than 1kb of data , again this works for every one else and i will check removing set_flashdata() option with him.

Comment: looks like its trying to parse it as an image? is the header correct?

Comment: @tomexsans it shows this message and didn't redirect to any where , even though i have a code in between redirect and set flash data that insert record to database , this code work perfect again what make me crazy i have never seen this issue although i have tested the same page on many computers !

Answer (score 1):

Set the **Session Flash** Data as above

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('updateprofile','Your Profile has been Updated');
```

to print this data in the view use

`<?php if($this->session->flashdata('updateprofile')): echo $this->session->flashdata('updateprofile'); endif;?>`

Comment: This is not the case , i already do that what happen is when i set flash data it shows coockie content as in image above !

Comment: cant say heard this for first time

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error: miss `)`
Isn't necessary to use array in this case
try to change this:

```
$this->session->set_flashdata(array('success_msg' =>'Some message');
```

to this

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg','Some message');
```

make sure error reporting is enabled, or try placing the following at the top of your index.php.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_WARNING | E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
```

Comment: Sorry it's not the case , i forgot to copy this )
and as i said it works for me and my friends but not for this customer

Comment: The double arrow operator is only valid in an array declaration, removing the array bit will cause another syntax error

Comment: no errors it just shows cookies content as if i did echo $this->session->all_userdata ();