# How check the size byte of paragraph string UTF-8 by php?

Tags: php, utf-8, byte

I have UTF-8 string as bellow:

```
Công ty tnhh một thành viên
```

I visit web: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter and filter text utf-8 in textarea.

It will show "That’s 27 characters, totaling 32 bytes. #"

So, how to check byte text `utf-8` equal `"32 bytes"` with php?

I have been using function **strlen()** but return result is **27**, not **32**.

Thank very much!

Comment: Possibly [`strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) and [`iconv_strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv-strlen.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure string size in Bytes in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568949/measure-string-size-in-bytes-in-php)

Comment: Thank very much! But, I have been using function strlen() but return result is 27, not 32.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` is what you're looking for, from the php website:

> **Note:**
>   strlen() returns the number of bytes rather than the number of characters in a string.

see more at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)