# How to know how many bytes sent to client?

Tags: php

Is it possible to know how many bytes sent to the client browser using php? My pages are created dynamically, so the size isn't fixed.

Comment: Possibly duplicated answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507985/php-determine-how-many-bytes-sent-over-http

Comment: @LandelinDelcoucq I don't think that question covers OP's use case...

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to know the size?

Answer (score 3):

Using php's [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

```
// start output buffering
ob_start();

// create your page

// once the page is ready, measure the size of the output buffer
$length = ob_get_length();
// and emit the page, stop buffering and flush the buffer
ob_get_flush();
```

As usual with php, these functions are pretty well documented in the standard documentation, don't forget to read the user contributed notes.

Comment: ob_get_length(), nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You can see this in your webserver's access log file.

But you can also code some php to get an answer like this:

```
ob_start();

echo "your content"

$data = ob_get_contents();

$size = strlen($data);
```

see also: [Measure string size in Bytes in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568949/measure-string-size-in-bytes-in-php)